# Find Uncorrelated Items in Dataframe

Tags: r

Let's say I have three columns in a table like the one below.

If I was trying to find **only** the Gene IDs that **weren't** correlated (or have a poor correlation) between the columns `Sample_1` and `Sample_2`, how would one go about this?

| Gene ID | Sample_1 | Sample_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ENSG00000000003.15 | 8.0 | 4.0 |
| ENSG00000000005.6 | 106.0 | 62.0 |
| ENSG00000000419.13 | 93.0 | 166.0 |
| ENSG00000000457.14 | 69.0 | 63.0 |
| ENSG00000000460.17 | 284.0 | 300.0 |
| ENSG00000000938.13 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| ENSG00000001036.14 | 379.0 | 201.0 |
| ENSG00000001084.13 | 544.0 | 586.0 |

Would I use the corrr package?

```
corrr::correlate(your_data, method = "pearson")
```

Comment: I'm a little uncertain about what your goal is.  But with just two columns to correlate (Sample_1 and Sample_2), it seems like you will have only one correlation coefficient and one p-value. These alone don't say much about which of the genes were not correlated.

Comment: a simple solution is to make a scatter plot, and see which observations veer off

Answer (score 0):

you could try this approach:

Think of cor_tab as your dataframe.

```
library("Hmisc")
res2<-rcorr(as.matrix(cor_tab))
flattenCorrMatrix <- function(cormat, pmat) {
  ut <- upper.tri(cormat)
  data.frame(
    row = rownames(cormat)[row(cormat)[ut]],
    column = rownames(cormat)[col(cormat)[ut]],
    cor  =(cormat)[ut],
    p = pmat[ut]
    )
}
flat_cor <-flattenCorrMatrix(res2$r, res2$P) 
flat_cor$p <- round(flat_cor$p, 3)
flat_cor[order(flat_cor$p),]
```

Now you could get only correlations below a certain p value using this:

```
flat_cor %>% .[grep("Sample", .$column), ] %>% .[.$p <= 0.05, ]
```

Of course that also works in the other direction (e.g., poor correlation as indicated by p > .05)